# BASH: AWK - find the smallest and largest number with condition "if"

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, conditional-statements, min

I've got syntax problem with awk and I don't know how to fix it:

```
 awk -F: -v lim=100 '{if ($1 >= lim)} NR == 1 {line = $0; min = $1} NR > 1 && $1 < min {line = $0; min = $1} END {print min}' file.txt
```

I want to get printed the smallest number in $1 column but greater than 100. It's works fine but without condition "if".

Answer (score 3):

Try this awk:

```
awk -F: -v lim=100 '(!min || $1 < min) && $1 >= lim {min=$1} END{print min}' file.txt
```

If there is no number >= 100 then it will just print 0.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I tried to do the same but I've always had an error.

Comment: @Smugli: See updated code. Also can you tell me what error are you getting?

Comment: @AkshayHegde: Tanks for your comment, I have changed the code to fix the problem.